# How to trigger another method or task based on testcase failure or skipped or pass in xctest framework

Tags: swift, ios11, xcode9, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I am writing UI test cases in swift using xctest framework.

I want to trigger another task(such as taking screenshot or ) based on testcase pass or fail or skip. My current code is below

```
  import Foundation
  import XCTest

  class HomePageChromeUITests: XCTestCase {

var pathStr:String = ""
override func setUp() {

    super.setUp()
    continueAfterFailure = false
    self.launchWithUserLoggedIn()
}

override func tearDown() {
    super.tearDown()
}

func testHomePageChrome_10385() {
    let app = XCUIApplication()


    let backButton = app.buttons[AccessibilityIdentifiers.PageEditorBackButton]
    let editButton = app.buttons[AccessibilityIdentifiers.PageEditorEditButton]

    XCTAssertTrue(backButton.exists && backButton.frame.origin.x < editButton.frame.origin.x, "Back button does not exist.---10385")
    XCTAssertTrue(!editButton.exists, "Edit button does not exist.---10385")

 }
}
```

I want to trigger a method whenever testcase fails and pass my failed message there That is "10385".

How can i achieve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered wrapping `XCTAssert` methods in your own that will call method you want _and_ call corresponding `XCTAssert`? I know it's not the best solutions since it require to manually rewrite some subset of `XCTAssert` methods, but it still seems the obvious one.

Comment: I think about that. But actually i am having three ui test bundle and around 500 test methods in xctest and around 600 assert for that. So writing new wrapper will be costly i think and needs code modification in every assertion. Is there any other way?

Comment: @AutomationUser I have added an answer for this. Please implement it and let me know your feedback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In XCode 9 Apple changes its previous XCTestObservation to XCTestObservationCenter. You will find the reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestobservationcenter)

To do something based on the TC pass or fail you need to register the testObserver and add it to your test.

Here is the complete implementation for this.

Step 1: Create a class called observer.

```
 import Foundation
 import XCTest

 class Observer: NSObject, XCTestObservation {
var failedTC = 0

func testBundleWillStart(_ testBundle: Bundle) {
    print("Test bundle started")
}

func testBundleDidFinish(_ testBundle: Bundle) {
    print("Test bundle Finished")
}

func testSuiteWillStart(_ testSuite: XCTestSuite) {
    print("Test suite started")
}

func testSuiteDidFinish(_ testSuite: XCTestSuite) {
    print("Test suite ended")
}

func testSuite(_ testSuite: XCTestSuite, didFailWithDescription description: String, inFile filePath: String?, atLine lineNumber: Int) {
    print("Test suite failed, information: " + description)
}

func testCaseWillStart(_ testCase: XCTestCase) {
    print("Test case started")
}

func testCaseDidFinish(_ testCase: XCTestCase) {
    print("Test case finished")
}

func testCase(_ testCase: XCTestCase, didFailWithDescription description: String, inFile filePath: String?, atLine lineNumber: Int) {
    print("Test case failed. Message: " + description)

    var tmpMsgArr = description.components(separatedBy: ".---")
    let testcaseID = tmpMsgArr[0]

    print("------" + testcaseID)

    yourAwesomeMethodThatWillbeCalledWhenTCFails() // implement this method that you want to execute

    failedTC += 1
}

}
```

Step 2: Add this observer to your test. For adding observer code is here.

```
  let observer = Observer() // Your created observer class
  let observationCenter = XCTestObservationCenter.shared()
  observationCenter.addTestObserver(observer)
```

**Note:** Remove the observer when you break down your tests or you will get multiple invocations and multiple calls on test events if you add an observer on every `setUp`.

In your case rewrite your set up method like below:

```
 override func setUp() {

    super.setUp()
    continueAfterFailure = false

    let observer = Observer() // your created observer class
    let observationCenter = XCTestObservationCenter.shared()
    observationCenter.addTestObserver(observer)

    self.launchWithUserLoggedIn()
}
```

Hope this complete example will help you.

Comment: i tried your answer and i am expecting exactly what you said.

Comment: I use this solution for taking screenshot on fail. And I have duplicates of screenshot. It seems that observers increments with each test case when we add it in setUp. What the solution to have only one observer?

Comment: I have tried remove Observer in tearDown but it was not helped.

Comment: Solution is override setUp of class method https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/understanding_setup_and_teardown_for_test_methods. I think you should update your answer.

Comment: Both testcase & testsuite's didFailWithDescription methods throws "Instance method 'testSuite(_:didFailWithDescription:inFile:atLine:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'testSuite(_:didFailWithDescription:inFile:atLine:)' of protocol 'XCTestObservation'" message. Should I make it private? @Mahmud Riad

Answer (score 2):

You should subclass `XCTestCase` and override the function `recordFailure(withDescription:inFile:atLine:expected:)` then have all your test cases inherit from this new class.

This method will be called whenever a test fails.

```
import XCTest
class SomeSubclass: XCTestCase {

override func recordFailure(withDescription description: String, inFile filePath: String, atLine lineNumber: Int, expected: Bool) {
    super.recordFailure(withDescription: description, inFile: filePath, atLine: lineNumber, expected: expected)
    //Take your screenshot here
}
}

class TestClass: SomeSubclass {
//Your tests..
}
```